# HomeAssistant: Companion App sensors won't trigger automation

Tags: sensors, home-assistant

I use the latest version of app (2024.1.5-full) and HA (2024.3.0) and want to use the `next alarm` sensor as a trigger for an automation in HA. So I

- Enabled that sensor on the phone (it grabs the correct time of the next alarm),
- Added Android System and the alarm app I use to the `allow list` (nor sure if actually necessary, but oh well...),
- Set the sensor update frequency to `fast while charging` and connect my phone to a charger to make sure that sensors are updated every minute,
- Gave the HA app `background access` to continuously run in the background,
- Activated the `next alarm` sensor in the `mobile app` integration, and
- Verified, that the phone's sensor changes show up in HA in the logbook (they do and they show the correct values, e.g. `2024-03-11T07:00:00+00:00`)

Now, I have created an automation for "time" as in `When the time is equal to the entity my_phone`. Next alarm and add my automation actions:

```
alias: Morning light
description: ""
trigger:
  - platform: time
    at: sensor.my_phone_next_alarm
condition: []
action:
  - service: light.turn_on
    metadata: {}
    data:
      brightness: 120
      transition: 15
    target:
      device_id: 019abc309c83cf3152e60b37ab1ea554
mode: single
```

When I select "run" to manually test this automation, everything works as intended. Only problem is: the automation is not triggered when the alarm time is reached.

Moreover: When I add the condition that the automation should only be executed when my phone is connected to my local WiFi (sensor "WiFi Connection"), it ignores the condition apparently:

```
alias: Morning light
description: ""
trigger:
  - platform: time
    at: sensor.my_phone_next_alarm
condition:
  - condition: state
    entity_id: sensor.my_phone_wifi_connection
    state: MyAwesomeWiFiSSID
action:
  - service: light.turn_on
    metadata: {}
    data:
      brightness: 120
      transition: 15
    target:
      device_id: 019abc309c83cf3152e60b37ab1ea554
mode: single
```

With this second example, the light turns on when I run the automation manually - EVEN IF I previously disconnect my phone from my WiFi network (i.e. they shouldn't turn on because of said condition). Without running all that manually, the automation is obviously not triggered at all as the first example wasn't, too.

Any advice on this? How do I get this automation to work properly?

Comment: I would suggest that you join the HomeAssistant Discord server and ask in the #Automations channel. There is tremendous expertise there. Additionally, many, if not all, of the dev hang out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, boy was I surprised when this morning, the light turned on as planned even though the automation didn't work when testing it.

My assumption would be that the sensor's data values are not propagated in time in HA? All in all, the "Next Alarm" sensor had the updated value in time when testing - and the sensor update schedule says "immediate" in the app. Leaves as the only explanation that the sensor's data is not immediately available to automations.

Can anyone confirm/correct this hypothesis?

Comment: please do not ask a question inside an answer, especially when the answer is deemed to be correct